# Pattern matching while trying to parse IIS logs with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to parse the IIS log files which contains about 6000 lines using powershell. The sample lines are as below,

```
2014-07-11 10:12:18 172.20.154.136 POST /STAD/Listener/DocFWBOLListener.asp - 80 - 172.20.44.112 Java/1.6.0_20 200 0 0 3790
2014-07-11 10:12:25 172.20.154.136 POST /STAD/Listener/DocFWBOLListener.asp - 80 - 172.20.44.112 Java/1.6.0_20 200 0 0 2730
2014-07-11 10:12:31 172.20.154.136 POST /STAD/Listener/DocBOLAdviceConfirmListener.asp - 80 - 172.20.44.112 Java/1.6.0_20 200 0 0 2386
2014-07-11 10:12:34 172.20.154.136 POST /STAD/Listener/DocBOLAdviceConfirmListener.asp - 80 - 172.20.44.112 Java/1.6.0_20 200 0 0 3244
2014-07-11 10:12:34 172.20.154.136 POST /STAD/Listener/DocFWBOLListener.asp - 80 - 172.20.44.112 Java/1.6.0_20 200 0 0 3900
2014-07-11 10:12:41 172.20.154.136 POST /STAD/Listener/DocFWBOLListener.asp - 80 - 172.20.44.112 Java/1.6.0_20 200 0 0 2870
```

I need to match the `POST /STAD/Listener/DocBOLAdviceConfirmListener.asp` and also obtain the time taken field, which is the very last entry in each line. I've written the below script to parse the file but the pattern matching fails and returns the `cannot index into null array` error. Could someone help me with the regular expression part. Thanks.

```
$Filepath = "C:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\W3SVC1"
$Filen = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filepath | Select-Object -Last 1
$Filename = ($Filen).FullName
$Pat1 = "^.*(DocBOLAdviceConfirmListener).* (\d{1,})$" 
#$Pat2 = "^.* (\d{1,})$"
#$data = ''
$Count1 = 0
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $Filename, 'Open', 'Read', 'ReadWrite'
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $stream, $true
    $reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, 'Begin')
    while (-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()

        #$line
        if ([regex]::Matches($line,$Pat1,"IgnoreCase")) { 
            $DocBolACLValue = $matches[2]
            if ($DocBolACLValue -gt 3000) {
                $Count1 += 1
            }
        }
    }

    $reader.Close()
    $stream.Close()
    $Count1
```

Comment: The regex works fine for the sample log you included. If you get errors, enable line printing(uncomment `#$line`) and gives us a sample that includes the line that fails.

Comment: I used ($line -match $Pat1) and it works fine. The earlier [regex]::Matches fails. I will try to get the value for $line and post it. Thanks for the help. Is there any performance hits if we use -match operator?

Comment: `-match` pretty much does the same, and is the "powershell-way" to do regex-matching. AFAIK you shouldn't notice any difference in performance.

Comment: Have you considered using [`LogParser`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/microsoft-logparser/) instead of PowerShell?

Comment: I realize that it's not as fancy as RegEx, and your pattern match evidently works, but you could just do a `.Split(" ")` on each line instead it seems. Just offering an alternative if this continues to give you headaches.

Comment: @Ansgar I can't use *LogParser* as I need to leverage this script in SCOM monitoring. I actually ended up using the *-match* operator and it seems to do the task just fine for now. TheMadTechnician I completely agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Filepath = "C:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\W3SVC1"
$Filen = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filepath | Select-Object -Last 1
$Filename = ($Filen).FullName
$contents = get-content $Filename

foreach($item in $contents)
{
    $regex1 = [regex]::Match($item,"\d+:\d+:\d+","ignorecase")
    $regex2 = [regex]::Match($item,"/STAD/Listener/DocBOLAdviceConfirmListener.asp","ignorecase")
    if($regex2.Success -eq $true)
    {
        $combined = $regex1.value + " " + $regex2.value
        $combined #displays matching lines
    }   
}
```

I hope this works for you.

T.CK